# how to develop using google_sign_in api on mac M1 (Apple silicon)

Tags: xcode, flutter, dart, google-signin, apple-m1

I recently started developing a project using flutter on M1 mac, all my dependencies work fine except [google_sign_in](https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in) .
the pod file and `pubspec.yml` file are tagged. [image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJLfr.png), [image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSLUm.png)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1 - delete podfile, podfile.lock and pods folder from `yourApp/ios` folder

2 - run `flutter clean`

3 - run `flutter pub get`

4 - Go to the folder `yourApp/ios` and run `pod update`

5 - run `flutter build ios` from `yourApp` folder

Comment: That dosent seem to work can you eloborate a little more , please

Comment: added a more complete solution, please upvote if it solves your problem

Comment: your solution is unrelated; you propose fix for iOS, but issue is with macOS. `google_sign_in: ^6.2.1` still does not work on macOS M1.

Answer (score 1):

GoogleSigin package is not compatible with Apple silicon remove it from your project as it has now been a year and is unlikely to ever be supported

Comment: is there any workaround for adding that ?